# How the heck do I return these arrays with actual values from the db? Keep on coming up blank

Tags: php, mysql

So the ultimate goal is to print out products as objects in a table using functions from these classes, but the output is a table with the correct amount of rows/columns but they are blank. I've spent 3 hours trying to figure this out and I'm stumped. There's three files

Product.php

```
<?php

class Product
{
    protected $product_id;

    protected $product_name;

    protected $product_price;

    public function __construct($product_id,$product_name, $product_price = '')
    {
        $this->setProductID($product_id);
        $this->setProductName($product_name);
        $this->setProductPrice($product_price);

    }


    public function getProductID() {
        return $this->product_id;
    }
    public function getProductName() {
        return $this->product_name;
    }

    public function getProductPrice() {
        return $this->product_price;
    }

    public function setProductID($product_id)
    {
        $this->product_id = $product_id;
    }
    public function setProductName($product_name)
    {
        $this->product_name= $product_name;
    }

    public function setProductPrice($product_price)
    {
        $this->product_price= $product_price;
    }


}
```

ProductMapper.php

```
<?php

class ProductMapper
{
    public function getProducts()
    {
        $dbConn = getDbConnection();

        $stmt = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM product");
        $stmt->execute();

        $outArray = array();

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $outArray[] = new Product($row['product_id'], $row['product_name'], $row['product_cost']);
        }

        return $outArray;
    }
}
```

and Index.php which is where it is outputted.

```
<?php

require('classes/functions.php');
require('classes/Product.php');
require('classes/ProductMapper.php');

$productMapper = new ProductMapper();
$rows = $productMapper->getProducts();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Product</title>


</head>
<body>


    <tbody>
    <?php

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$row->getProductID($this)}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row->getProductName($id)}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row->getProductPrice($id)}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason to send the values back to the Product constructor inside the loop ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few minor issues with the code that you provide which prevent it working. Do you have 'error_reporting' set [error-reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)?

index.php :

- The 'getProduct' methods do not accept any parameters. So you should not call them with any parameters.

ProductMapper.php :

- for consistancy i renamed the 'product_cost' column to 'product_price'.
- i injected the database connection in the constructor and made it a property. Makes available the connection for any future method.

Some example output:

```
pid01   name-pid01  23.34
pid02   name-pid02  101.67
```

Here are the new scripts...

index.php

```
require('classes/functions.php');
require('classes/Product.php');
require('classes/ProductMapper.php');

$productMapper = new ProductMapper(getDbConnecton());
$rows = $productMapper->getProducts();

// note: the 'getProductID', 'getProductName' and 'getProductPrice' methods
//       do not accept or need, any parameters.

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Product</title>

</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <?php

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$row->getProductID()}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row->getProductName()}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row->getProductPrice()}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
// ProductMapper.php
class ProductMapper
{
    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    private $dbConn = null;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo)
    {
        $this->dbConn = $pdo;
    }

    public function getProducts()
    {
        $dbConn = $this->dbConn;

        $stmt = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM product");
        $stmt->execute();

        $outArray = array();

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $outArray[] = new Product($row['product_id'], $row['product_name'], $row['product_price']);
        }

        return $outArray;
    }
}
```